# I am not receiving mail php

Tags: php, forms, post, html-email

I have a problem with receiving mail. I have tried different mail providers (microsoft, yahoo, gmail) and still not receiving mail. I am working on web site for my friend and I bought a bootstrap template with php contact.

I am using xampp and I have tried sending the mail that way and I have upload it on some other friends web site in sub folder and still not receiving it.

Here is the code:
HTML index.php

```
<form class="js-contact-form" role="form" action="mail/contact.php" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
                        <div id="msgInfo"></div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control wow fadeInLeft name" data-wow-delay="0.2s" placeholder="Name" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter name">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control wow fadeInLeft email" data-wow-delay="0.4s" placeholder="Email" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter email">
                        <textarea class="form-control wow fadeInLeft message" data-wow-delay="0.6s" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter message"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">Send message</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the contact.php code:

```
<?php
// PHP script for sending email
//
// Configuration
//

$toEmail = "";                                          // replace with your email where you would like to send email
$subject = 'Contact form from my website';              // replace with subject you want to receive
$body    = 'You have received email from website:';     // replace with text that you want to receive in email
$from    = '';                                          // replace with email that will look like sender

//
// ----- do not edit after this line if you don't understand what you are doing -----
//

if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo "Invalid input";
    return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body .= "\n";
$body .= "Name: $name\n";
$body .= "Email: $email\n";
$body .= "Message: $message\n";

$headers = "From: $email\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $toEmail";

$res = mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo "OK";
return true;
?>
```

This isn't my first time that I am working with php, in the past I had a working php(2-3 years ago) and I have tested that also but it doesn't work -.-

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Can you try to `var_dump($_POST);` and did you tried to replace all `$_POST` (e.g `$_POST['name']`, etc.) by static value ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add name attribute for all input/textarea tags in your form so you can find them in your $_POST array

```
<form class="js-contact-form" role="form" action="mail/contact.php" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
                    <div id="msgInfo"></div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control wow fadeInLeft name" data-wow-delay="0.2s" placeholder="Name" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter name" name="name">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control wow fadeInLeft email" data-wow-delay="0.4s" placeholder="Email" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter email" name="email">
                    <textarea class="form-control wow fadeInLeft message" data-wow-delay="0.6s" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required data-parsley-error-message="Enter message" name="message"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1s">Send message</button>
</form>
```

and change this line in your php code ($ToEmail variable is always empty)

```
$res = mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

with this

```
$res = mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: I have put on purpose $toEmail empty because there you put your email where you want to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with this

```
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "Name: ".$name."\n";
$body .= "Email: ".$email."\n";
$body .= "Messagee: ".$message."\n";
```

and change the headers:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
$headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

**Update**

```
if($res){
echo "OK";
}
else{
echo "failed."

}
```

By this you can know whether your mail function in working or not. 
Enable errors in php if not enabled using:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```